# Twitter adding an extra parameter in my tweets

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter

So I use the `history.pushState` method to push a url path to the url like so :

`history.pushState('', '', 'share/' + image[1] + '');`

So the url looks something like `localhost:3000/share/sjdfhsdjf4j3grfksajdhgfa.png`

So then I do the `onClick` event in JavaScript :

```
$('.share_btn_twitter').on('click', function() {
  var link = window.location.href;
  console.log(link);
  window.open('http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url='+ link +'&hashtags=random', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top='+($(window).height()/2 - 225) +', left='+$(window).width()/2 +', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
});
```

So this works fine across all browsers on desktop and the native browsers for devices like Safari for iOS.

However, I use Chrome on iOS and the url I'm tweeting now looks like :

`localhost:3000/share/share/sjdfhsdjf4j3grfksajdhgfa.png`

It adds an extra `/share/` in, has anyone got any idea what's going on? Or could point me in the right direction I'm having difficulties debugging this issue because it's so weird.